# Reduce a data frame to fewer rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let us say I have a data frame "dat" like:

```
 col1     col2
  12       a
  43       a
  54       a
  11       a
  33       b
  43       b
  34       c
  34       c
  342      c
  343      c
```

Now I have a vector as

```
vec <- c(a,a,a,b,c,c)
```

What I want to do is to remove extra rows in data frame "dat" as per vector "vec" which means in the data frame keep only **first 3** rows corresponding to "a", keep only **first 1** row corresponding to "b" and keep only **first 2** rows corresponding to c.

I should get the output as

```
 col1     col2
  12       a
  43       a
  54       a
  33       b
  34       c
  34       c
```

What is the fastest way to do without having to use for loop?

Comment: 'merge' will work if you create a seq_along value within each letter category.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way using `split` and `Map`:

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text=' col1     col2
  12       a
  43       a
  54       a
  11       a
  33       b
  43       b
  34       c
  34       c
  342      c
  343      c',stringsAsFactors=F)

vec <-  c('a','a','a','b','c','c')
```

**Solution**

```
#count frequencies
tabvec <- table(vec)

data.frame(do.call(rbind,
   #use split to split data.frame according to col2
   #use head to only choose the first n rows according to tabvec
   #convert output into a data.frame
   Map(function(x,y) head(x,y),  split(dat, as.factor(dat$col2)), tabvec)
))
```

**Output:**

```
    col1 col2
a.1   12    a
a.2   43    a
a.3   54    a
b     33    b
c.7   34    c
c.8   34    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
#create a data frame with frequencies
tv <- data.frame(table(vec))

#filter values       
group_by(dat, col2) %>%
filter(row_number() <= tv$Freq[tv$vec %in% col2])
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#Groups: col2
#
#  col1 col2
#1   12    a
#2   43    a
#3   54    a
#4   33    b
#5   34    c
#6   34    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `Map()` approach.

```
fvec <- factor(vec)
## find the index for the first occurrence of a new level
m <- match(levels(fvec), df$col2)

df[unlist(Map(seq, from = m, length.out = tabulate(fvec))), ]
#   col1 col2
# 1   12    a
# 2   43    a
# 3   54    a
# 5   33    b
# 7   34    c
# 8   34    c
```

Or you could use `rle()` after matching

```
rl <- rle(match(vec, df$col2))
df[unlist(Map(seq, rl$values, length.out = rl$lengths)),]
#   col1 col2
# 1   12    a
# 2   43    a
# 3   54    a
# 5   33    b
# 7   34    c
# 8   34    c
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be also done by after creating a sequence colum

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dat)[, N:= 1:.N, col2], col2, N)
dat[setDT(list(col2=vec))[, N:=1:.N, col2]][, N:= NULL][]
#   col1 col2
#1:   12    a
#2:   43    a
#3:   54    a
#4:   33    b
#5:   34    c
#6:   34    c
```

Comment: Nice.  I was trying to figure out a DT answer for a while

Answer (score 1):

Using `Base R` functions can be done:

**Data**

```
    dat <- read.table(header=T, text=
   ' col1     col2
      12       a
      43       a
      54       a
      11       a
      33       b
      43       b
      34       c
      34       c
      342      c
      343      c')
    
    vec <-  c('a','a','a','b','c','c')
```

**Procedure**

```
dat[unlist(lapply(table(vec), function(x) 1:x))+match(vec, dat[,2])-1,]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  col1 col2
1   12    a
2   43    a
3   54    a
5   33    b
7   34    c
8   34    c
```

Answer (score 0):

With Base R, you can use `subset` + `ave` + `table` like below

```
> subset(df, ave(col2, col2, FUN = seq_along) <= table(vec)[col2])
  col1 col2
1   12    a
2   43    a
3   54    a
5   33    b
7   34    c
8   34    c
```